# A better way rather than using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've got the following query which works fine and gives me the result I'm after. It takes 3 seconds to return the results however and I find that too slow.

Anyone know a better way?

```
SELECT 
    @PrimaryKey = ccu.Column_Name 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu on 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
WHERE 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' and 
    tc.Table_Name  = @TableName 
    --tc.Table_Schema = 'LookUp'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised your query would take so long but you can get the same information via the SQL Server catalog views:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.indexes AS i
JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE
    i.is_primary_key = 1
    AND i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTable', 'U');
```

Comment: As a follow up, here's a good article on the tradeoffs between `information_schema` and system views: https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views